# Память элементов vector'a

Tags: c++, vector, heap

Где хранятся значения vector'а? В стеке или в куче? Или может быть где-то ещё.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main(){
  vector<int> a;
  a.push_back(1);
  cout << &a[0];
}
```

На моей машине выводит: 0x101009180. И я полагаю, что выделяется память в куче.
Поправьте, если не прав.

Comment: А вы проверьте. Напечатайте адрес самой переменной `a`, напечатайте адрес чего-нибудь, выделяемого `new`. И сопоставьте.

Comment: @avp, я понимаю, что сама переменная `a` будет выделена на стеке. Но мне интересно именно элементы вектора.

Comment: За то время, что вы набираете вопросы, можно уже самому написать `cout << &a[0] << '\n' << &a << '\n' << new int << '\n';`, запустить и сделать выводы

Comment: @apv, Ну получается, что я был прав. Так?

Comment: Конечно. Главное, что теперь вы увидели путь, которым можете проверять свои гипотезы

Comment: Интересно было бы посмотреть на реализацию, которая так **не** делает :)

Comment: @Harry from Kiev,  если только пользовательский класс.

Comment: @Александр, *значения vector'а хранятся в элементах вектора*, а элементы вектора хранятся в куче, потому что иначе не  было динамического роста. В стеке хранятся элементы таких оберток,, как std::array, std::valarray, которые имеют фиксированное количество элементов.

Comment: Никто в принципе не мешает сделать для вектора подобие so(вроде даже предложения в стандарт были) и после этого вопрос заиграет новыми красками

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да даже пользовательская... Выделять и перераспределять память на стеке (контейнер-то *динамический*, размер меняется на ходу)? Как минимум, стек очень быстро окончится. Во-вторых, будут еще те проблемы при вызове функций и передаче в них ссылки на такой класс: все, что будет выделено во время ее работы в стеке, умрет при завершении функции. Нет, я себе такое представить не могу...

Comment: @Harry from Kiev,  если создать связь между объектами std::array при помощи, например сигналов и слотов, то, думаю(не пробовал), можно как нибудь  строить кустарный состав. Хотя, как не делай, получится что вы правы _ не выйдет ничего полезного.